# How to Replace a Value in a String in Column with a Do Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of telephone numbers.  Some of them contain two continuous hyphen "--" instead of one "-".  I would like to replace the "--" with "-".
The problem is if the "--" appears only once for each cell, then that's fine, but it may have situations like "----" or "---", or even "-----------".  My hunch is to use a Do While or Until Loop, but I don't know how.  And I think I will need the Find Function, but I don't know how to combine them.
Can somebody kindly enough help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub rep()

For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Cells ' Change the range that you want

    If InStr(c.Value, "--") > 0 Then
        deli = Split(c, "-")
        For a = 0 To UBound(deli)
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "--", "-")
        Next a

    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly.  Thank you.  Can you please share with me what is the logic of this code? I understand the deli is an array, that what's for loop of UBound for?  Thanks.

Comment: First, `Split()`Func­tion returns one dimen­sional array con­tain­ing the sub­strings, after split­ting the main string based on the delim­iter `-`. Once you have split the string you can loop each sub-string and replace `--`by `-`.  Display your local window and debub using F8 to see how the code run.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to debug.

Comment: press `F8` in order to debug

Comment: Eh, I tried, but apart from Excel shows me some code higlighted in yellow, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Incredibly complicated and unefficient answers I see !!!

```
Range("c3:c17").Replace "--", "-"
Range("c3:c17").Replace "--", "-"
```

should do the trick in 2 lines for up to 4 hyphens, and probably much faster than the complicated answers. Add a third line for handling up to 6 consecutive hyphens.

If the number of consecutive hyphens can be really large (not as in the OP) then the following loop might be better:

```
With Range("c3:c17")
    Do Until .Find("--") Is Nothing
        .Replace "--", "-"
    Loop
End With
```

Don't forget that accessing the spreadsheet from VBA is an expensive operation. Using 1 replace for a range is way faster than doing it cell by cell. Of course this will only be visible if you handle large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes, but that can only works as "----", but sometimes the data are more nastier, such as "-----------------------".

Comment: @lukayl: The OP specified: up to 4 hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CorrectTelephoneNo()

    Dim strHypens
    strHypens = "--"
    Dim strFound As Boolean
    strFound = True 'Assuming there is atleat on cell with "--"
    Do While (strFound = True)
        'Replace all the "--" with "-"
        Cells.Replace What:="--", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        'Check if there are any more numbers with "--"
        On Error GoTo x
            strFound = Cells.Find(What:="--", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            GoTo y
x:          strFound = False

y:     Loop
    MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  This one can do the trick too. But I think the first Dim strHypens is not necessary, as you used "--" exclusively in your code later?  And I find some parameters in the replace lines are not necessary, like LookAt, SearchOrder, etc?  Thanks.

Comment: Correct, strHypens  is not required. To respond back immedietly i recorded the replcae and find. So it has some additional patrameters :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive function to do this for example:

```
function recursiveReplace(text as string, oldText as string, newText as string) as string
    dim result as string
    result = replace(text, oldText, newText)

    if instr(1, result, oldText) > 0 then
        recursiveReplace = recursiveReplace(result, oldText, newText)
    else
        recursiveReplace = result
    end if
end function

sub test()

    const phoneNumber as string = "234-45---34----112"
    debug.print recursiveReplace(phoneNumber, "--", "-")

end sub
```

You can now call this function directly in an excel worksheet too! For example =recursiveReplace("234---456-----67--5", "--", "-")

Comment: This only works as one cell at a time.  Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

Will a formula suffice to replace the -- with a -? 
Something like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","-")
```

In VBA, there are various ways, but here's one which will give you an idea of looping etc...

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceDashes()

Dim r As Range, r1 As Range
Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

For Each r1 In r
    If InStr(1, r1.Value, "--") >= 0 Then r1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(r1, "--", "-")
Next

End Sub
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: The For Loop only replace "--" once.  as the Cell values contain more "--", such as "----" or "---", the result will not eliminate those.  seems it still needs with Do Loop.

Comment: Erm. can you not just add an extra if statement for each case... perhaps :) For the formula part - something like: =IF(ISERROR(FIND("---";A1));A1;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"---";"-")) and add as many as you like. The VBA will just be a copy paste for an extra line for each case of --,---,---- etc

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Dim my_switch As Boolean
my_switch = True
Do While my_switch = True
   If InStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, "--") > 0 Then
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, "--", "-")
   Else
      my_switch = False
   End If
Loop
```

Comment: You can change it to any range.

Comment: Sorry, it is not working.  I think I got the hang of Do Loop.  No need of my_switch.  Not as elegant as @iDevlop, but it's my own:  
'set mphone = thisworkbook.worksheets(1).range("A2:A10")  
dim aCell as Range  
For Each aCell In MPhone
    Do While InStr(aCell.Value, "--") > 0
    
    aCell.Value = Replace(aCell.Value, "--", "-")
    
    Loop
    
    Next aCell'

Comment: Great. If that works for you - we are all happy. Good luck.